# Why does mssql use so much memory and take so long?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I have been working with mssql npm package using nodejs and noticed the performance is much slower than running the same query within SSMS.

An example of this is a simple query of `select * from contacts`. In the given table there are about 38000 rows and 14 columns. Running this query causes the node process memory usage to skyrocket to around 2GB and takes over thirty seconds and ultimately crash with a heap error. The same query in SSMS takes two seconds and memory usage stays low.

I am trying to understand the difference between the two. I know SSMS is a full software product, however, I would expect similar performance between the two.

Any insight anyone may have would be appreciated and below is example code I created for testing query times.

I have tried using streaming methods and the results are the same as well as a few other methods listed on their npm package page for retrieving results from the database.

```
var express         = require('express');
const mssql         = require('mssql');

var app             = express();

const config = {
    user: 'XXX',
    password: 'XXX',
    server: 'XXX',
    database: 'XXX',
    pool: {
      max: 10,
      min: 5,
      idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    }
}

var query = 'SELECT * FROM contacts'

app.get('/query', async function () {
  var connection = await mssql.connect(config);
      var result = await mssql.query(query)
      await mssql.close()
      console.log(result)
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 6000);
```

Expected Results: Low memory usage and quick query return time

Actual Results: High memory usage and long query times

Comment: Do you *really* need everything single column and every single row?

Comment: In some cases yes, we are syncing data between crm and a marketing automation platform and a full data set is required.

Comment: Yeah...it seems there is just too much data. JS isn't really great for high memory intensity tasks. If you really need to work on all the data at once, then you might need to look into how to do that in a more memory friendly way, like streaming it or caching parts and similar things. Otherwise, you should just limit the amount of data you take at once. This isn't exactly unique to Node - a server written in any language that tries to take too much records will eventually choke and die. SSMS is likely not grabbing all in memory.

Comment: 38000 records, but how "wide" are the columns? Are there things like addresses or "notes" fields with hundreds or thousands of characters? That adds up. The SSMS tool might open a result set stream, while your code as posted asks for the entire table in one big lump.

Comment: [Streaming info](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#streaming)

Comment: The longest column in this particular dataset is around 90 characters. Streaming the data does help, however, SSMS still is able to accomplish this query in around 2 seconds while node is taking over 30. I'm fully prepared to understand I just have to live with the results, I was just hoping to understand it a bit more.

Comment: @TJSouthern again, SSMS is not exactly comparable. I can't verify myself but I **strongly** suspect it's not just dumping all the data in memory in the same fashion that Node would try to do.

Comment: can your flow for this job change? i.e. if you're pulling all your contacts from db to server app then back to (another?) db could you not cover the job in say a stored-procedure you trigger from nodejs to take advantage of that 2s execution time. When it is complete use a more defined `select field1,field2 from contacts` to show any required data output on screen (rather than the heavy `select *...`)?